# python rocketry reschedule a scheduled task

Tags: python, schedule

In my project I'm using Rocketry for scheduling some tasks. the function I'm using for my task is the same for all of them but the schedule is different. e.g

```
def func(...):
  ...

for i in range(10, 20):
  app_rocketry.task(name=f"func{i}", func=func, start_cond=every(f"{i**2} minutes"))
```

my problem is I have to change the schedule in runtime in a scenario. what I need to do is to not change the schedule, I mean for example if that task is being run every 5 minute, I keep it as is but delay the next run and so force.

for example task is going to run at 12:00 and it's scheduled for every 5 minutes. in 12:03 I wanna change the next run to be at 12:08 not 12:05 and the run afterwards be based on this modification. what can I do and the main question is if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

a collegue's trick

```
class MyTask():
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_schedule = ''
    
    def do_something(self):
        print("TASK DONE")

    def __call__(self):
        # this magic method makes the instance callable as a function
        self.do_something()


my_task = MyTask()
for i in range(10, 20):
    my_task.time_schedule = f"{i**2} minutes"

    # since 'my_task' is passed as a function the __call__ method will be called
    app_rocketry.task(name=f"func{i}")(my_task)
```

Comment: well, actually it's not the answer to my problem. maybe I described it badly. I was looking for something like a `postpone` for example; but it simply isn't provided for the time being. btw I liked the way you're defining the tasks and thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your use case, but you could reschedule the task, something like

```py
app_rocketry = Rocketry()

@app_rocketry.task(daily.at('12:05'))
def my_task():
    print('Hello World')
    reschedule(5)

def parse_schedule_time(input:str)->tuple[int, int]:
    pattern = r"(\d+) hours?(?:, (\d+) minutes?)?"

    import re
    match = re.search(pattern, input)

    if match:
        hours = int(match.group(1))
        minutes = int(match.group(2))
        return (hours, minutes)
    else:
        return None

def reschedule(add_minutes: int):
    # The output looks like "task 'None' 12 hours, 5 minutes - 13 hours, 5 minutes"
    current_condition = app_rocketry.session[my_task].start_cond
    
    hours, minutes = parse_schedule_time(str(current_condition))
    
    if hours is not None:
        total_minutes = hours * 60 + minutes
        total_minutes += add_minutes
        new_hours, new_minutes = divmod(total_minutes, 60)
        app_rocketry.session[my_task].start_cond = daily.at(f'{new_hours}:{new_minutes}')
```

The most important part of this is the

```py
app_rocketry.session[my_task].start_cond
```

This variable gives us the start condition, be mindful of the task name `my_task`.

I do not know if Rocketry gives us a way of parsing the time more easily so I wrote something simple to do it, but there are some edge cases that it doesn't account for.

The code as is would probably cause a loop, since the task would run every 5 minutes after being "postponed".

Comment: what I did at the time was delete and add the task again. something really manual but worked nicely.